# Redo the function if url doesn't change

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm filling two forms that has different urls using selenium python. The script fills the first form and click on a submit button to go to the second form. Sometimes, It does not go to the second form, it stays on the first one.

What I want to do is to check if the url stays the same after clicking on the submit button, the script redo the process and refill the first form again, if the url changes, the script continue working normally.

This is what I tried so far

```
first_url = 'http://example.com/1'
check = driver.current_url

while True:
    if first_url != check:
        break
    else:
        form1() # function that fills the first form
```

The problem I am facing is that the first form continue to fills after that, the script doesn't skip the check and moves to the next functions. I want to do only one check that's all.

Code of the first form

```
def form1():
    try:
        driver.get(site)
        mission = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mission"]/option[1]'))).click()
        service = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="service"]/option[4]'))).click()
        phone = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="phone"]'))).send_keys('+15041245829')
        email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="email"]'))).send_keys('test@email.com')
        submit = driver.find_element('id','submit').click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Code of the second form

```
def form2():
    try:
        date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="date"]/option[1]'))).click()
        time = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="time"]/option[2]'))).click()
        submit = driver.find_element('id','submit').click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

And I've added the check to a function

```
def check():
    while True:
        check = driver.current_url
        if first_url != check:
            break
        else:
            form1()
```

I execute the code like that:

```
form1()
check()
form2()
```

Comment: why wouldn't the submit button not work?

Comment: I don't know, no error is printed. The script clicks on the button but the page only refresh and don't go to the next form. You can say that I get this error once in 6 tries.

Comment: if you could provide more code, it would be helpful.

Comment: in form2 you never do driver.get(second_url)

Comment: when I click on the submit button on the first form, it redirects me to the second form, so I implemented the Webdriverwait to wait for the element to show up before clicking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## update

**form1->**

```
def form1(site,driver):
    try:
        driver.get(site)
        # since you never call these elements of the page there is no need to store them in variables
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mission"]/option[1]'))).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="service"]/option[4]'))).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="phone"]'))).send_keys('+15041245829')
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="email"]'))).send_keys('test@email.com')
        submit = driver.find_elemnt(By.ID,'submit')
        submit.click()
        current_url = driver.current_url
        if not check(site,current_url):
            form1()
        else:
            return
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**form2->**

```
def form2(driver):
    try:
        # since you never call these elements of the page there is no need to store them in variables
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="date"]/option[1]'))).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="time"]/option[2]'))).click()
        driver.find_element('id','submit').click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**check->**

```
def check(url1,url2):
    if url1 == url2:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

**main->**

```
site = 'https://www.example.com'


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

form1(site,driver)
form2(driver)
```

if this doesn't work then the issue is probably from the click on the submit button and without a link i cant help with that you have to keep testing yourself.

Comment: it keeps looping on the first form (form1), it does not break from the while loop. I need the script to continue the process after one check is done. That's the problem I am facing

Comment: i cant help you with very limited code, include more so i can see the structure of it

Comment: I've updated the code, please check

Comment: Updated solution

Comment: Thank you it worked. one last question please, if I have any other function that come after the form2(), should I add them in the `if not` as well?

Comment: No you add it after calling form2, in main.